# Apache Activiti with NoSql Database

Tags: activiti, nosql

We are planning to use Apache Activiti as an embedded application in our Microservice, we are already using a NoSql DB for our service and would like to re-use the same for the Workflow Manager. Does Activiti supports NoSql and has someone tried it before. Are there any other good workflow management frameworks which can be used with NoSql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activiti does not explicitly support noSql databases although some testing was done some time back against the Cockroach database :

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/11/running-flowable-cockroachdb.html

If I remember correctly, the testing was actually done with Activiti rather than Flowable at the time.

However, this likely doesnt meet your requirements for using your existing noSql repo.

So, I would recommend looking at the Flowable project (http://www.flowable.org/).
This is a fork of the Activiti 6 community edition and they have recently abstracted the history data persistence for the very purpose of enabling persistence in non traditional databases.

I believe this change was made in the 6.1 release, check the blog here:
http://www.flowable.org/blog/2017/06/27/flowable-6.1.0-release.html

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Thank you @ Greg. Release Notes talks about only History tables which can be moved to NoSql. How about Process Instance related runtime tables?

Comment: Unfortunately there are foreign keys in the runtime tables (tasks, to instances, instances to definitions) making it difficult to move these to a noSql store. Not saying it's impossible, but probably not a trivial undertaking.